# What is the latest version of Java JDK and Java Runtime Environment (JRE) respectively?

Tags: java, macos, installation, version, macos-catalina

What is the latest version of Java JDK and Java Runtime Environment (JRE) respectively?
My versions are

````
❯ java --version
java 14.0.1 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
❯ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    14.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 14.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    13.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 13.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.5, x86_64: "AdoptOpenJDK 11"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
❯ /usr/bin/java --version
java 14.0.1 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
❯ /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)```
````

Comment: @OlafKock Please refrain from sarcasm, [be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) instead

Comment: I didn't think of my comment as sarcastic, rather as a genuine listing of reasons why I consider this question unanswerable an not a good fit for stackoverflow. Whatever is answered today will be outdated tomorrow (for certain values of tomorrow) when someone finds this question and its answer, thus it provides no value for future readers. Sorry if this came over sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

Currently 14 is newest. But early-access version also exists https://jdk.java.net/16/

JDK minor versions are various by vendors.

You can see popular vendors from https://sdkman.io/jdks

Since JDK is superset of JRE, there's no need of JRE if you installed JDK

=== Added@2021-09-15 ===

New versions are released every half year.

Comment: Since 14 is the newest version of JDK, my java --version shows the newest version of java?

```❯ java --version
java 14.0.1 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)```
Also even though there's no need of JRE if you installed JDK what is the latest version of just JRE?

Comment: Yes. If you want just execute some java programs, then JRE is enough. In your case, you installed JDK which contains JRE.

Comment: what is the latest version of just JRE? What number? I know the latest version of JDK (JAVA DEVELOPMENT KIT) is 14, what is for only JRE (JAVA RUNTIME ENVIRONMENT) seperately? @Donggi Kim

Comment: The latest version is 16 now.